# Unable to upgrade to 14.04

Tags: 14.04

I know very little about Linux/Ubuntu, but have intermediate experience with Apple & Microsoft OS.

A lady friend has asked me to assist her with a severe problem on her Linux 64Bit Platform.

We don't live in the same city. Therefore I have been using TeamViewer Remote access, to try and help troubleshoot for solutions.

She is unable to enter data into any address/search bars, due to a stream of equal signs like this preventing her from doing so;

========================================================================

Also unable to update FireFox.
She was able to download the latest version of FireFox, from a link that I emailed her, but we are unable to execute the file.

Also unable to update Ubuntu 14.04, from Ubuntu 13.04.
She was able to download Ubuntu 14.04, from a link that I emailed her. But we are unable to execute the file.

Comment: Does this only happen in your browser? As it sounds like a stuck key. Does it keep happening if you unplug your keyboard? "Certain attachments" is rather unspecified. Which program, what attachments and are there error messages. Also, as you intend to update to 14.04 but have yet to do so, it would help if you said which version you are currently using.

Comment: Thanx Adaephon, for your assistance...I just updated my question. I hope that it is as simple as a stuck key. We shall check on that. Also I deleted my statement about 'Certain attachments' from my question. As I'm unsure which attachments are unopenable. But there have been no error messages.

Comment: Pretty sure this is a stuck key because of old keyboard (Either laptop, desktop or a cat is sitting on the keyboard right now). Apart from that, what do you mean with "unable to execute the file". Did you download the ISO and burn it on a DVD or USB? or are you trying to execute an ISO like an EXE?

Comment: Adaephon and Luis Alvarado, you were both correct in your assumption of a possible stuck equals ( = ) key. My friend couldn't believe it, so she thanks you very much for this.

Comment: Yes Luis, I was trying to execute the unzipped package for FireFox to begin with, by looking for a file which would appear to be similar to an .EXE as in Windows OS.

Comment: @doot777, what kind of files did the zip archive contain? Linux is very different from Windows. Pretty much any file could be the executable, and .exe extensions are not used at all.

Answer (score 2):

Upgrading an operating system that is in bad condition can take all day.

If your operating system has become degraded to a certain extent, it starts to become a good idea to backup your data on that computer and do a clean install. A clean install only takes a half hour to do, and it will save you from doing a lot of mucking about. Run the Ubuntu live DVD before you install anything to check if your problem with the stream of equal signs in address bars is hardware or software based.

Comment: Thankyou Karel for your suggestions...I am soon to do this proceedure for a Microsoft OS, because has become so corrupted...

Comment: I notice that you have added more information to your question since I posted my answer and it is apparent that the reason why your friend can't update directly from 13.04 to 14.04 is that no one can, as 13.04 is end of life. However there is a hacky way to circumvent this described in [Can I skip over releases when upgrading?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/34430/can-i-skip-over-releases-when-upgrading). It's not so easy to manage this remotely via TeamViewer though. Also when reinstalling 2 OSs you should always install Windows before Ubuntu, and let the Ubuntu installer setup the dual boot.

Comment: Karel I applaud your efforts, in taking the time to give me the info regarding updating Ubuntu from 13.04 to 14.04. I shall certainly look into the link that you have supplied. I have a friend who is Linux savvy, and hopefully he can guide us through this process...We'll attempt to update soon, and let you know how we go! In regards to the Microsoft OS that I discussed, that is a separate computer althogether, with no Linux to be installed. (Sorry but I didn't get to finish that question before, and I am unable to edit it now)

Comment: I have a LogMeIn account for remote support, but I am yet to utilise this on a Linux computer from my iPad. I have found LogMeIn to be a lot more fluid and responsive than TeamViewer, but LogMeIn costs $80 per year, for access to two computers only. Whereas TeamViewer is free.